# Split ID and Name from multiColumncombobox to Textbox using Kendo UI library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the `Kendo UI` library have a difficult time wanting help:

[image]

When I select an attribute in the `combobox`, the ID and name from the `combobox` will separate and put into each `textbox` as shown in the picture. And here is my code.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
        .Name("ma_icdchinh")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "display: inline-block;width: 9.33%;", disabled="disabled"})                       
        )
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiColumnComboBox()
        .Name("customers")
        .DataTextField("displayElement.value")
        .DataValueField("codeElement.value")
        .Filter("contains")
        .FilterFields(new string[] { "codeElement.value", "displayElement.value" })
        .Columns(columns =>
            { 
                columns.Add().Field("codeElement.value").Title("Mã").Width("100px");
                columns.Add().Field("displayElement.value").Title("Tên").Width("auto");
             })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "display: inline-block;width: 89.33%;margin-left: 0px;" })
        .Height(200)
        .DataSource(source =>
             {
                 source.Read(read =>
                     {
                         read.Url("/api/fhir/valueset/icd10");
                     })
                       .ServerFiltering(false);
             })
    )
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the picture to your post.

Comment: sorry, I have updated my picture in post!